# Package system is broken (Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: 12.04, package-management, updates, system

Keep trying to update Ubuntu 12.04 but it keeps telling me that my package system is broken. I run apt-get -f install and get this :

```
    owner@MyLaptop:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
[sudo] password for owner: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  thunderbird-globalmenu linux-headers-3.5.0-34-generic
  linux-headers-3.5.0-32-generic compiz-plugins compiz-plugins-main
  python-compizconfig python-central linux-headers-3.5.0-23
  linux-headers-3.5.0-32 linux-headers-3.5.0-34 linux-headers-3.5.0-23-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  indicator-session
The following packages will be upgraded:
  indicator-session
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 399 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/75.8 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
dpkg: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 12465 package 'indicator-session':
 `Depends' field, reference to `libcairo2':
 `>' is obsolete, use `>=' or `>>' instead
dpkg: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 12465 package 'indicator-session':
 `Depends' field, reference to `libcairo2':
 version value starts with non-alphanumeric, suggest adding a space
dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 12465 package 'indicator-session':
 `Depends' field, reference to `libcairo2': version contains ` '
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

The details I get from the update manager are:

```
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:

indicator-session: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.3.6-6~) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.10 is installed
                   Depends: libcairo2 (>= } 1.2.4) but 1.10.2-6.1ubuntu3 is installed
                   Depends: libdbus-glib-1-2 (>= 0.78) but 0.98-1ubuntu1.1 is installed
                   Depends: libdbusmenu-glib4 (>= 0.4.2) but 0.6.2-0ubuntu0.1 is installed
                   Depends: libdbusmenu-gtk3-4 (>= 0.4.2) but 0.6.2-0ubuntu0.1 is installed
                   Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0) but 2.26.1-1 is installed
                   Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.26.0) but 2.32.3-0ubuntu1 is installed
                   Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.0.0) but 3.4.2-0ubuntu0.7 is installed
                   Depends: libgudev-1.0-0 (>= 147) but 1:175-0ubuntu9.3 is installed
                   Depends: libpango1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0) but 1.30.0-0ubuntu3.1 is installed
```

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks.

EDIT: This is what I get when I run apt-cache policy indicator-session:

```
    indicator-session:
  Installed: 0.3.96-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 0.3.96-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     0.3.96-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
 *** 0.3.96-0ubuntu1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Please add the output of `apt-cache policy indicator-session` to your question.

Answer (score -1):

`sudo apt-get clean` 
it will clean the repository 
or
you `dpkg` is installing another package in Ubuntu software center or in another terminal. or you break any package during installing.
check that and run
`sudo apt-get update`

Comment: ok I ran sudo apt-get update and then ran sudo apt-get -f install and got the same results

Comment: have u try sudo apt-get clean?

Comment: @michigankid79 please try **sudo apt-getautoremove**, **sudo apt-get autoclean** and finally try **sudo apt-get update** and **sudo apt-get -f install**. and reply please